# TDS items not showing up after deployment

Tags: tds

I'm trying to set up a new TDS project on an existing solution (Sitecore version 10). The solution contains a couple of TDS projects. I configured my new TDS project as existing ones but my new Sitecore items not showing up after deployment and deployment not throwing any error.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you check in the TDS project's properties (Build tab) that the connection is successfully established or not for the new TDS project? and did you sync the Sitecore item properly via the "Sync with Sitecore" option?

Comment: Build tab configuration same as the others, but I find out in the website's TDS project's multi-project properties tab, there is a field for package bundling field and this field contains the other TDS projects except mine, so I checked mine too, but the result still remains same. I use Sync with Sitecore property in my local environment but I need something for packaging in other environments.

Comment: @Bdemirbas How you are creating new TDS project. Can you copy paste any of existing TDS project and amend your changes. In this way you don't need to worry about existing project settings.